# How to use stateful requests in Loopback 4?

Tags: loopbackjs

In v3, we could define middlewares on underlying Express, such as [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), to add a `session` property on requests objects.

In v4, it looks like there is no equivalent for this, and the underlying Express is not exposed.

I am migrating an authentication provider from v3 to v4 and I'm stuck because of that. How can I do?

I tried the following workaround but it didn't work:

```js
import { MyApplication } from './application';
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@loopback/core';

const expressSession = require('express-session');

export { MyApplication };

export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
  const app = new MyApplication (options);
  // @ts-ignore
  app.restServer._expressApp.use(expressSession);
  await app.boot();
  await app.start();

  const url = app.restServer.url;
  console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);
  console.log(`Try ${url}/ping`);

  return app;
}
```

Comment: Has you been able to solve this? I'm trying to implement Azure AD OIDC and having the same struggle.

Comment: Well my issue still seems to be open after one year and a half (see the answer) and the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/) still states that some features of Loopback 3 are not implemented in Loopback 4 yet, so I guess you'll have to contribute or wait!

Comment: I made it work, using the "express-session" package, an global interceptor and a custom store that injects a session repository to save the session temporary. I still have to create some functionality to destroy the session if required to delete it. Ill post my solution later on.

Answer (score 3):

Hello from the LoopBack team :)

We haven't looked into supporting HTTP sessions and stateful requests yet. Ideally, session handling should be implemented as a new Sequence action - see [Sequence docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Sequence.html).

```js
class MySequence {
  // skipping constructor with dependencies to be injected

  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    try {
      // the following line is new
      const session = this.restoreSession(context);

      // the default sequence continues here
      const route = this.findRoute(context.request);
      const params = await this.parseParams(context.request, route);
      const result = await this.invoke(route, params);
      await this.send(context.response, result);
    } catch (error) {
      await this.reject(context, error);
    }
  }
}
```

The sequence action `restoreSession` should:

- check if there are any session cookies present in the request
- load the session if a cookie was provided, maybe create a new one otherwise?
- bind the session in our [Context](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Context.html) so that other places like controllers can receive the session via [Dependency Injection](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Dependency-injection.html)

Could you please open a new GitHub issue (a feature request) in [loopback-next](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues) so that we can discuss implementation specifics there?

Comment: As you suggested I created a feature proposal: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1863